# Pass string or wstring in a function

Tags: c++

I want simplify the code to use the same function for both ANSI and UNICODE string version

```
tstring formatW(const std::string format, ...);
tstring formatA(const std::wstring format, ...);
```

in a single parametrized function

```
tstring format(const tstring format, ...);
```

However if I use this as, I get an error in line 3

```
  const std::string fmtA =  "MouseWheel nFlags %u,zDelta %d, CPoint(%d,%d";
  std::string strA  = formatA(fmtA, nFlags, zDelta, pt.x, pt.y );   // Ok
  std::string strA2 = format (fmtA, nFlags, zDelta, pt.x, pt.y );   // Fail :(

  const std::wstring fmtW = L"MouseWheel nFlags %u,zDelta %d, CPoint(%d,%d";
  std::wstring strW  = formatW(fmtW, nFlags, zDelta, pt.x, pt.y);  // Ok
  std::wstring strW2 = format (fmtW, nFlags, zDelta, pt.x, pt.y);  // Fail
```

The error I get is this:

> error C2664: ~tstring Format(const tstring,..'.)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::string' to 'const tstring'

I am not familiar with parameteized functions.

Comment: Presumably, you have defined `format` as a macro for either `formatA` or `formatW`, depending on `#define UNICODE`. So `std::string strA2 = formatW(...)` is clearly wrong. Likewise, `std::wstring strW2 = formatA(...)` is also wrong.

Answer (score 5):

`char` and `wchar_t` (the underyling types of string/wstring) are not compatible (8 and 16 bits) so you cannot combine them inside a runtime-checking environment.

That is why Windows for example has 2 versions for many functions (MessageBoxA, MessageBoxW etc).

Solution: use a class that stores data as UTF-8 (char) then converts them to 16-bit when wchar_t is needed. Or better, vice versa (uses wchar_t internally and converts data to UTF-8 when a char* is needed).

Comment: runtime-checking environment ? I tought template parameters functions gernerate compile time checked functions,  2 function versions, one for char and one for wchar_t?

Comment: Yes, compile time. Your problem is at run time because the size of the passed types is different - and size matters in that case.

Comment: Do I have understand right: We should use nowadays  preferable std::string over std:wstring. std::wstring only if when is needed. Then there is usually no need to write for us a second function (like formatW)?

Comment: all internal processing should be done in wide chars. Use the UTF-8 version only when necessary(for example, when sending an e-mail).

Comment: Really the wide string answer depends on whether your computer and API has "Microsoft" in its name. UTF8 has solved the "code page" problem on the web and is pretty much the accepted answer on unix. UTF8 is not hard to parse, and stays efficient for English, will on average be better than wide char for European languages, makes little difference to other "small character set" languages, but does cost more storage for Chinese and other large character set languages, but equally, as unicode has matured, it no longer properly fits into a 2-byte word.

Comment: @Michael Hm...  I come from [link](http://utf8everywhere.org/)
Basically they says:  I recommend avoiding std::wstring on Windows or elsewhere, except when required by the interface, or anywhere near Windows API calls and respective encoding conversions as a syntactic sugar.
My confusing is now greater...

Comment: @tom: The *"UTF-8 Everywhere"* movement is dogmatic, rather than pragmatic. It fails to address the single most important aspect: Character encoding matters only in information **interchange**, i.e. when data enters or leaves your application (e.g. writing a file, sending data over a socket, etc.). Inside your application, you can (and probably should) use UTF-16LE, Windows' native character encoding, encoded as `wchar_t`. The *"UTF-8 Everywhere"* movement also fails to acknowledge, that UTF-16 *is* everywhere (Windows, Java, .Net, ...).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have good reasons not to just do the Microsoft `#ifdef UNICODE` thing? It is a bit rubbish, I admit.

You can't check them at runtime, but this is exactly what c++ compile-time overloading was invented for.

So you probably need to do 3 different things:

1) Write 2 function prototypes that give you the behaviour you need

2) Convert them to take a variadic template argument list instead of ...

3) encapsulate it all in a templated class.

1) To declare and implement the two helper functions with the same name, just do that. The compiler will distinguish them based on the first parameter:

```
tstring format(const std::string& format, ...);
tstring format(const std::wstring& format, ...);
```

Of course you then end up writing the same boilerplate code twice, something like:

```
tstring format(const std::string& format, ...) {
  va_list format;         /// hmm va_list with references - may need a tweak!
  va_start(format, __arg);
  return vformatA(format, __arg);
}
```

And it is a pain writing this twice for each method you merge.

2) To use the variadic templates, Declare and implement your functions as:

```
template <typename... T>
tstring format(const std::string& format, const T& ... t)
{
  return formatA(format, t...);
}
```

Again you need to write this twice. It isn't too complex compared to the c-style variadics, so you might accept that.

3) A third optional step is to write a Helper template class. So the idea of this is that the actual implementation is performed in a helper class, which you only define for string and wide string. To be honest all it does is add bulk and force you to implement both methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use templates and limit them to only string and wstring type, so

```
template <typename T>
T format(const T format, ...);
```

and later declare two functions that will do what you want according to the type, so

```
std::string format<std::string>(const std::string format, ...){...}
std::wstring format<std::wstring>(const std::wstring format, ...){...}
```

Comment: That's not how you define a function [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). Apart from that, using [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) makes the implementation *significantly* easier (even type safe, if you so choose). Making `format` a [string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) allows the function templates to be called with string literals, too, without creating temporary `std::string`/`std::wstring` objects.

Comment: @llnspectable C++14 that is all new and a little confusing to me, can you show the correct declaration.  My first try: 

'template<typename T, typename... Targs>
T format(std::string_view fmt,  Targs { .. }'

Comment: @tom: Something like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OujC2ZXFu5VdyzVJ).